# Set background color for DataGrid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, triggers

I am working on a program where I use a `GroupingGrid` (included at the bottom of this post in case it is needed.  In this grid, which is built off a `DataGrid`, I am creating a sort of Aero effect to match a `TreeView` in the application, which is going to be converted to a grouping grid (we built it wrong).  I want the text to be vertically centered and the background of the selected row to be a blue gradient when active and a gray gradient when unactive (such as when the window lost focus).  Initially, I just defined these values in the page theme:

```xaml
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFD9F4FF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF9BDDFB" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEEEDED" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

The `HighlightBrushKey` sets a blue gradient and the `ControlBrushKey` sets a gray gradient for when the window is not active.

However, I want the text in the cells to be centered, which I accomplished through:

```xaml
<controls:GroupingGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</controls:GroupingGrid.CellStyle>
```

However, this shrinks the textboxes within the cell, which is where the background is set, so it appears with a narrow band of blue behind the direct text and a band of white on either side.  To solve this problem, I set the cell highlight color to Transparent and assigned the grid row color like:

```xaml
<Style x:Key="PrettifyRow" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However, the problem now is that I cannot set the background to a gray gradient when the window is not active.  The `TreeView` I am basing it on uses this:

```xaml
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

`DataGrid`s do not have the `IsSelectionActive` property, so I attempted to use `IsFocused` instead.  Unfortunately, that did not work.  How can I get the highlight to work similarly to this?  From experimenting with this, I think there could be two ways to get this to work - either finding a different way to vertically center the text, or use an event to somehow determine when the selection is active.  In case it matters, I am not allowing the columns to populate automatically - I manually state which ones to populate.

Here is the `GroupingGrid`, as promised:

```xaml
<DataGrid x:Class="Rubberduck.Controls.GroupingGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Expander Background="WhiteSmoke" Foreground="Black" Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="True">
                            <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DataGridRowsPresenter></DataGridRowsPresenter>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

#### Edit:

I tried setting the template by wrapping each cell in a `Grid`.  That did not work because it messed up the row formatting, although the text was centered.

Comment: Which rows do you want to highlight ? - What shall trigger the background ?

Comment: @FeDe I edited my question to state that (see the first paragraph).  Does this help?

Comment: Try to post a gif using ScreenToGif utility.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reverse the trigger, and set an original brush when the condition is false.

**Some thing like that:**

```
<Style x:Key="PrettifyRow" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
    </Trigger>
 <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{put here the original brush or set it to be transparent}" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

In addition use the BasedOn syntax to preserve the original style (`BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}"`), when you re-styling some control.

Regards,